# Converse of the one-dimensional maximum principle

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, maximum-principle

If a positive function $u:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is known to be continuous and twice differentiable, and to have no local maxima in $(0,1)$ (i.e. $u$ is maximised on the boundary $\{0,1\}$), is it possible to find bounded $g(x)$ and negative $h(x)$ such that the one-dimensional maximum principle applies

$$u''+g(x)u'+h(x)u\geq 0$$

and if so, is there a way to construct such $g,h$?

Comment: What do you mean by "such that the one-dimensional maximum principle applies"? Do you want to show that $u$ must achieve it's extremums at the boundary of $[0,1]$ (i.e. the points $0$ and $1$)?

Comment: doesn't $u$ have a maximum and thus a local maximum

Comment: @Quoka yes, but not exactly. The function $u$ is known to achieve its maximum at the boundary, and it may have a local minimum inside. 
The max principle gives conditions to this. i.e., if $u$ is such that there exist $g$ bounded and $h$ negative with 
$$u'' + gu'+hu\geq 0).$$ I am looking for the converse statement.

Comment: @mathworker21 yes, I meant no local maxima in $(0,1)$ (maxima are at the boundary). Corrected now

Answer (score 1):

No, in general this is not possible. If $u$ has a critical point $x_0$ with $u'(x_0) = u''(x_0) = 0$, then the left-hand side at $x_0$ is $h(x_0)u(x_0)<0$. As an example, take $u(x) = 1 + (x-1/2)^3$ and $x_0 = 1/2$.

However, if all critical points are non-degenerate, then your assumption implies that $u''(x_0)>0$ for every $x_0$ with $u'(x_0) = 0$. In this case you can take $g(x) = C u'(x)$ for a large constant $C>0$, and $h(x) = -\epsilon$ for a small constant $\epsilon > 0$ and check that the condition is satisfied.

Comment: The examples you gave work at the critical points where we know that $u''(x_0)>0$, but not in other points $x$. In fact, in your case one can trivially take $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=-1$.
The inequation of the maximum principle applies to all points in the interval.

Comment: This is meaningful in my case, because I do not have access to those critical points.

Comment: @Tal-Botvinnik: In the example, if you take $g=0$ and $h=-1$, then $u''(x_0) + g(x_0)u'(x_0)+h(x_0)u(x_0) = -u(x_0) < 0$, so this does not work. I am not sure exactly what you are taking issue with in my answer.